# api manager-how to configure master-datasource xml file to our identity server db instead of api manager db

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-identity-server

regarding single sign on,i need web UI authentication as well backend  API authentication,
i have installed wso2 Identity Server and API manager, both having individual db for users, i need to configure Identity Server db .In API manager in master-datasource.xml file how to configure.
what i have to add here master-datasource.xml.
kindly suggest in case wrong.

Comment: You can refer this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Identity+Server+as+IDP+for+SSO. What is the APIM version you are using?

Comment: APIM version 3.1.0, already refereed same link and given shared user store and registry having db concepts, i have already db WSO2SHARED_DB in identity server ,need to use this existing db..user
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Identity+Server+as+IDP+for+SSO

Comment: What is your exact requirement? In APIM 3.1.0, SSO has been automatically turned on and you don't have to configure anything and APIM can be used independently without the Identity Server.

Comment: In our product we have multiple services integrated to WSO2 identity server IDP  through an SP. One of those services require an API gateway to be placed in front of it to allow access to its API for a third party. Because of this, we wanted to sync the User DB of API gateway and identity server IDP.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your requirement is to use an API gateway along with your identity server. You can following our documentation to setup wso2 identity server as a key manager [1] with WSO2 API Manager. When you do this your user store of identity server will be shared with the API manager. Also all the key management related functionality will be done via your identity server

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager